How to enable or add text2vec-transformers module in Weaviate installed from GitHub running without docker
I'm trying to enable the text2vec-transformers module in Weaviate, which I installed locally from GitHub. I'm facing an issue where the --modules flag isn't recognized, and setting environment variables like WEAVIATE_DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE doesn't seem to enable the module.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Tried running Weaviate with the following command:
./weaviate --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080 --scheme=http --modules=text2vec-transformers

My question
How can I properly enable or add the text2vec-transformers module in a Weaviate
Also tried setting the following environment variables before running Weaviate:
export WEAVIATE_DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE=text2vec-transformers
export TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API="http://localhost:8080"

However, the module still doesn't seem to be enabled.
Ran curl http://localhost:8080/v1/modules to check installed modules, but the response shows no modules available.
I think the weaviate that i'm using from https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/releases does not contains any module

Please mention, where exactly are you stuck based on the following resource
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/model-providers/transformers/embeddings

Where are you seeing that --modules is a valid flag?
To enable modules, you need to use env vars. For example:
ENABLE_MODULES="text2vec-cohere,text2vec-databricks,text2vecopenai,generative-openai,generative-databricks"


Yeah I have used env vars then I run weaviate ./weaviate --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080 --scheme=http --modules=text2vec

try removing  --modules=text2vec

I remove it and used external model and create embedding
